# Get a list (without nested list) directly from a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to return a list with the interleaved elements of two lists directly from the list comprehension - without use a next step to flaten the result. Is it possible?

```
alist1_temp=[1, 4,2]
alist2_temp=[3, 7,4]
t=[[x,y] for x,y in zip(alist1_temp, alist2_temp)]
```

Return `[[1, 3], [4, 7],[2, 4]]`

But how can I get directly from the list-comprehension `[1, 3, 4, 7, 2, 4]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this with just `zip` to get it in that order that you want:

```
[i for j in zip(alist1_temp, alist2_temp) for i in j]
```

if you don't mind the order just do:

```
alist1_temp + alist2_temp
```

or get it with `itertools.chain` thanks to @buran:

```
import itertools

list(itertools.chain(alist1_temp, alist2_temp))
```

Comment: with the chain - why not just `list(itertools.chain(alist1_temp, alist2_temp))`? it's not comprehension, but I am not sure comprehension is strict requirement. And anyway the order of elements in the result is different.

Comment: @buran Right, surely you are right

Comment: @buran Edited, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

If you like numpy way of doing this, you could use this!

```
np.vstack((alist1_temp,alist2_temp)).flatten('F')
```

or you can flatten your list comprehension as well

```
np.array(t).flatten()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you specified that you want get it from from the list-comprehension:

```
alist1_temp=[1,4,2]
alist2_temp=[3,7,4]
L = len(alist1_temp)+len(alist2_temp)
t = [alist2_temp[i//2] if i%2 else alist1_temp[i//2] for i in range(L)]
print(t) #prints [1, 3, 4, 7, 2, 4]
```